# Exit sub routine after completion using batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am trying to reverse engineer multiple apk's using jadx through command line. To perform this task i'm using batch file. The commands in batch file are:

```
cd E:\MAL_DATASET\REV_CODE\DroidKungfu
MKDIR 0015ae7c27688d45f79170dcea16131ce557912a1a0c5f3b6b0465ee0774a452.apk
cd C:\Users\Home\Downloads\jadx-0.6.0\bin
cmd /C start /wait jadx -d E:\MAL_DATASET\REV_CODE\DroidKungfu\0015ae7c27688d45f79170dcea16131ce557912a1a0c5f3b6b0465ee0774a452.apk E:\MAL_DATASET\Derbin-data\chk_dir\DroidKungFu--------5\0015ae7c27688d45f79170dcea16131ce557912a1a0c5f3b6b0465ee0774a452.apk
cd E:\MAL_DATASET\REV_CODE\DroidKungfu
MKDIR 001e0f67b5bb9ddab14facbef94791eaed0eb939bcb651d19dafd0e2a05d8178.apk
cd C:\Users\Home\Downloads\jadx-0.6.0\bin
cmd /C start /wait jadx -d E:\MAL_DATASET\REV_CODE\DroidKungfu\001e0f67b5bb9ddab14facbef94791eaed0eb939bcb651d19dafd0e2a05d8178.apk E:\MAL_DATASET\Derbin-data\chk_dir\DroidKungFu--------5\001e0f67b5bb9ddab14facbef94791eaed0eb939bcb651d19dafd0e2a05d8178.apk
cd E:\MAL_DATASET\REV_CODE\DroidKungfu
MKDIR 00621e015191863041e78726b863b7e1374b17fda690367878d1272b0e44b232.apk
cd C:\Users\Home\Downloads\jadx-0.6.0\bin
cmd /C start /wait jadx -d E:\MAL_DATASET\REV_CODE\DroidKungfu\00621e015191863041e78726b863b7e1374b17fda690367878d1272b0e44b232.apk E:\MAL_DATASET\Derbin-data\chk_dir\DroidKungFu--------5\00621e015191863041e78726b863b7e1374b17fda690367878d1272b0e44b232.apk
```

The problem which i am facing is that every time the start/wait command executes, i have to mauaully exit the sub process window as shown in following picture:[image]

Is there any way that this process can be automated i.e. the sub process exits automatically. I have tried cmd /C but it doesn't works in this case. Thanks.

Comment: why are you calling cmd.exe inside of cmd.exe? also, you are running cmd /c which means it will close the cmd you called and then you are waiting for it in start?

Comment: What `cmd /c start /wait ... ` does is start up a new copy of cmd, which then executes the `start...` command. Do you really want to do that? Try removing the `cmd /c` from the beginning of those `start /wait ...` commands.

Comment: if i don't use cmd /c, every time a start / wait command executes, the command line asks about confirmation to terminate batch file (y/n)

Comment: @Hasnain. Then you are something is trying to terminate the batch manually.

Comment: What is `jadx`? a batch file, a console application, or anything else? Don't use `start` unless you really need it for some reason! If `jadx` is a batch file, use `call jadx ...`; if it is a console application, simply use `jadx ...`; if you do need `start` whatsoever, then use `start /WAIT jadx ...`, or, if needed for whatever reason, then use `start /WAIT cmd /C ...`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling cmd /c and start /wait which makes no sense.

```
cd E:\MAL_DATASET\REV_CODE\DroidKungfu
MKDIR 0015ae7c27688d45f79170dcea16131ce557912a1a0c5f3b6b0465ee0774a452.apk
cd C:\Users\Home\Downloads\jadx-0.6.0\bin
start /wait jadx -d E:\MAL_DATASET\REV_CODE\DroidKungfu\0015ae7c27688d45f79170dcea16131ce557912a1a0c5f3b6b0465ee0774a452.apk E:\MAL_DATASET\Derbin-data\chk_dir\DroidKungFu--------5\0015ae7c27688d45f79170dcea16131ce557912a1a0c5f3b6b0465ee0774a452.apk
cd E:\MAL_DATASET\REV_CODE\DroidKungfu
MKDIR 001e0f67b5bb9ddab14facbef94791eaed0eb939bcb651d19dafd0e2a05d8178.apk
cd C:\Users\Home\Downloads\jadx-0.6.0\bin
start /wait jadx -d E:\MAL_DATASET\REV_CODE\DroidKungfu\001e0f67b5bb9ddab14facbef94791eaed0eb939bcb651d19dafd0e2a05d8178.apk E:\MAL_DATASET\Derbin-data\chk_dir\DroidKungFu--------5\001e0f67b5bb9ddab14facbef94791eaed0eb939bcb651d19dafd0e2a05d8178.apk
cd E:\MAL_DATASET\REV_CODE\DroidKungfu
MKDIR 00621e015191863041e78726b863b7e1374b17fda690367878d1272b0e44b232.apk
cd C:\Users\Home\Downloads\jadx-0.6.0\bin
start /wait jadx -d E:\MAL_DATASET\REV_CODE\DroidKungfu\00621e015191863041e78726b863b7e1374b17fda690367878d1272b0e44b232.apk E:\MAL_DATASET\Derbin-data\chk_dir\DroidKungFu--------5\00621e015191863041e78726b863b7e1374b17fda690367878d1272b0e44b232.apk
```

Additionally, you do not have to CD to create DIR each time, you can cd to your bin once off, then mkdir with full path and just run `jadx` each time.

```
cd C:\Users\Home\Downloads\jadx-0.6.0\bin
MKDIR E:\MAL_DATASET\REV_CODE\DroidKungfu\0015ae7c27688d45f79170dcea16131ce557912a1a0c5f3b6b0465ee0774a452.apk
start /wait jadx -d E:\MAL_DATASET\REV_CODE\DroidKungfu\0015ae7c27688d45f79170dcea16131ce557912a1a0c5f3b6b0465ee0774a452.apk E:\MAL_DATASET\Derbin-data\chk_dir\DroidKungFu--------5\0015ae7c27688d45f79170dcea16131ce557912a1a0c5f3b6b0465ee0774a452.apk

MKDIR E:\MAL_DATASET\REV_CODE\DroidKungfu\001e0f67b5bb9ddab14facbef94791eaed0eb939bcb651d19dafd0e2a05d8178.apk
start /wait jadx -d E:\MAL_DATASET\REV_CODE\DroidKungfu\001e0f67b5bb9ddab14facbef94791eaed0eb939bcb651d19dafd0e2a05d8178.apk E:\MAL_DATASET\Derbin-data\chk_dir\DroidKungFu--------5\001e0f67b5bb9ddab14facbef94791eaed0eb939bcb651d19dafd0e2a05d8178.apk
MKDIR E:\MAL_DATASET\REV_CODE\DroidKungfu\00621e015191863041e78726b863b7e1374b17fda690367878d1272b0e44b232.apk
start /wait jadx -d E:\MAL_DATASET\REV_CODE\DroidKungfu\00621e015191863041e78726b863b7e1374b17fda690367878d1272b0e44b232.apk E:\MAL_DATASET\Derbin-data\chk_dir\DroidKungFu--------5\00621e015191863041e78726b863b7e1374b17fda690367878d1272b0e44b232.apk
```

and even better, in a batch file it will automatically wait for the process to terminate, so no need for the start wait. and because you are calling a batch just run it with cmd /c

```
cd C:\Users\Home\Downloads\jadx-0.6.0\bin
MKDIR E:\MAL_DATASET\REV_CODE\DroidKungfu\0015ae7c27688d45f79170dcea16131ce557912a1a0c5f3b6b0465ee0774a452.apk
cmd /c jadx -d E:\MAL_DATASET\REV_CODE\DroidKungfu\0015ae7c27688d45f79170dcea16131ce557912a1a0c5f3b6b0465ee0774a452.apk E:\MAL_DATASET\Derbin-data\chk_dir\DroidKungFu--------5\0015ae7c27688d45f79170dcea16131ce557912a1a0c5f3b6b0465ee0774a452.apk

MKDIR E:\MAL_DATASET\REV_CODE\DroidKungfu\001e0f67b5bb9ddab14facbef94791eaed0eb939bcb651d19dafd0e2a05d8178.apk
cmd /c jadx -d E:\MAL_DATASET\REV_CODE\DroidKungfu\001e0f67b5bb9ddab14facbef94791eaed0eb939bcb651d19dafd0e2a05d8178.apk E:\MAL_DATASET\Derbin-data\chk_dir\DroidKungFu--------5\001e0f67b5bb9ddab14facbef94791eaed0eb939bcb651d19dafd0e2a05d8178.apk
MKDIR E:\MAL_DATASET\REV_CODE\DroidKungfu\00621e015191863041e78726b863b7e1374b17fda690367878d1272b0e44b232.apk
cmd /c jadx -d E:\MAL_DATASET\REV_CODE\DroidKungfu\00621e015191863041e78726b863b7e1374b17fda690367878d1272b0e44b232.apk E:\MAL_DATASET\Derbin-data\chk_dir\DroidKungFu--------5\00621e015191863041e78726b863b7e1374b17fda690367878d1272b0e44b232.apk
```

Comment: if i don't use cmd /c, every time a start / wait command executes, the command line asks about confirmation to terminate batch file (y/n).

Comment: not possible. start /wait waits for the program to complete. if it is asking to confirm, it means you are trying to force the batch to terminate.

Comment: in fact you do not need to call start /w at all when running in batch file, it automatically does the wait.

Comment: No. If i don't use start /wait, all the start commands run in in parallel. Which in case of hundreds of commands hangs my system.

Comment: are you running this from cmdline or in batch file?

Comment: i am running through batch file. As per your last update, it only executes the first jadx command and than terminates.

Comment: very strange indeed. perhaps try the last edit again, I made some changes.

Comment: I have tried it. Still runs the first command, than i have to type exit in cmd and it goes for next command. Is there any way to make exit as a part of batch file after every jadx command?

Comment: wait. is jadx a batch itself as well?

Comment: ah ok. then try cmd/c without start/ wait or run it with -h or -? switch to see if there is an exit switch for it

Answer (score 2):

You may be able to make your batch file easier to adjust and read, for example:

```bat
@ECHO OFF
SET "srcDir=E:\MAL_DATASET\REV_CODE\DroidKungfu"
SET "binDir=%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%\Downloads\jadx-0.6.0\bin"
SET "chkDir=E:\MAL_DATASET\Derbin-data\chk_dir\DroidKungFu--------5"
SET "APK1=0015ae7c27688d45f79170dcea16131ce557912a1a0c5f3b6b0465ee0774a452.apk"
SET "APK2=001e0f67b5bb9ddab14facbef94791eaed0eb939bcb651d19dafd0e2a05d8178.apk"
SET "APK3=00621e015191863041e78726b863b7e1374b17fda690367878d1272b0e44b232.apk"

CD/D "%binDir%"
FOR %%A IN ("%APK1%" "%APK2%" "%APK3%") DO (
    IF NOT EXIST "%srcDir%\%%~A\" MD "%srcDir%\%%~A"
    CMD/S /C"jadx -d "%srcDir%\%%~A" "%chkDir%\%%~A"")
```